# Question about characterization of the Sobolev space $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I know that $u$ is Lipschitz continuous if and only if $u\in W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$. Now, if I consider the norm
$$
I_{\infty}:W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R},\qquad I_{\infty}(u, \Omega):=\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}
$$
where $\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}=\operatorname{ess\ sup}_{\Omega}|Du|$, with $|Du|=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|u_{x_i}|$, I do not understand why we can conclude that if $u$ is Lipschitz continuous (and then it belongs to $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$), then $I_{\infty}(u, \Omega)<+\infty$.

Some helps?

Thank You

Comment: Does this follow from the fact that $\|Du\|_{L^\infty}\leq \sum_i \|u_{x_i}\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|u\|_{W^{1,\infty}}$?

Comment: @Matt Can I conclude that $I_{\infty}(u, \Omega)<+\infty$ because $\|u\|_{W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)}=\|u\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}+\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}<+\infty$ (and hence $\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}<+\infty$)?

Comment: The Sobolev norm I think should be $\|u\|_{W^{1,\infty}} = \|u\|_{L^\infty} + \sum_i \|u_{x_i}\|_{L^\infty}$, which is slightly different from what you have written.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what $I_\infty (u,\Omega)<\infty$ has to do with $u$ being Lipschitz continuous in $\Omega$ (which BTW is not true without some regularity assumptions on $\Omega$). This is just by definition of the $W^{1,\infty}$ norm.

Comment: @Jose27 Yes. Indeed the fact that $u$ is Lipschitz continuous allows us to say that $u$ belongs to $W^{1, \infty}(\Omega)$, that implies that $I_{\infty}(u, \Omega)$ is finite.